# Google Maps on Android. How to draw a line along the border of cities, states etc?

Tags: android, google-maps

Now I am customize the Google Map, I wanna distinguish each city by line and fill inside with colors.

How can I do that?   Drawing a polyline by hand is only a solution ??

Answer (score 0):

May this can solve your problem.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes

Comment: Then, Should I draw a line by myself? Like any other object to handle borders?

Comment: yes. you need to draw line at boundary of city yourself.

Comment: Thank you, Sorry for not voting for you. I got lower reputation :(